# How to query data from Firebase on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am exploring Firebase capabilities and bumped with simple task to read the data from it.

Permissions to read and write were setup only for authorized users.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
            ".read":  "$uid == auth.uid",
            ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"   
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I keep in mind about cascade rules, so the path to the data is setup as `users/$uid`

Althought I don't have any callback call on my request.

```
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/" + uid);
    reference.orderByValue().addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {


        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Log.d(App.TAG, "onChildAdded: " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Log.d(App.TAG, "onChildChanged: " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(App.TAG, "onChildRemoved: " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Log.d(App.TAG, "onChildMoved: " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(App.TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }

    });
```

(the user is authenticated)

Do you see the issue I miss here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample of uploading the data:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!
database
    .child("actions")
    .child(uid)
    .push()
    .setValue(data)
```

This is how I get this data back:

```
database
    .child("actions")
    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
    .orderByKey()
    .addChildEventListener(eventListener)
```

And a general scenario covering up by `firebase-ui`:

```
val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .reference
    .child("actions")
    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
    .orderByKey()

val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Action>()
    .setQuery(query, Action::class.java)
    .build()

adapter = ActionAdapter(options)
```